# Some images not loading on github pages after deploying. React

Tags: reactjs, image, tabs, nav

Hi I deployed a new react app to ghpages. One of the pages has a Tab Container with 3 Nav Items that serve as a link. The first tab which auto loads with the page shows all the images correctly. The second and third tab do not show the pages. These images are rendered properly when I run it locally. They are all coded the same way. Anyone know how to solve this?
Link to ghpages https://johntrieseverything.github.io/starcraft2-unit-counter/
The error occurs under the "Units List" section when selecting the second or third tab.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
    <Tab.Container defaultActiveKey="Protoss" >
      <Container fluid className='unitListDisplayBackground'>\
        <Row style={{ height: '10vh' }}></Row>
        <Row className='mt-5'>
          <h1>Units List</h1>
          <p>This is a page where you can view all playable units and see their stats</p>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Nav fill variant='tabs' defaultActiveKey="/home">
            <Nav.Item >
              <Nav.Link
                style={{ backgroundColor: '#393e46', color: '#ADD8E6', marginBottom: '1vh' }}
                eventKey="Protoss">
                <img
                  src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/assets/Icons/Protoss Icon.png"}
                  alt='Protoss Icon'
                  style={{ width: '50px', height: '50px' }}
                /></Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link
                style={{ backgroundColor: '#393e46', color: '#ADD8E6', marginBottom: '1vh' }}
                eventKey="Zerg">
                <img
                  src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/assets/Icons/Zerg Icon.png"}
                  alt='Zerg Icon'
                  style={{ width: '65px', height: '50px' }}
                />
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link
                style={{ backgroundColor: '#393e46', color: '#ADD8E6', marginBottom: '1vh' }}
                eventKey="Terran">
                <img
                  src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/assets/Icons/Terran Icon.png"}
                  alt='Terran Icon'
                  style={{ width: '50px', height: '50px' }}
                />
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
          </Nav>
          <Tab.Content>
            <Tab.Pane eventKey="Protoss" style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
              {/* Display the Protoss Units */}
              <ProtossUnits />
            </Tab.Pane>
            <Tab.Pane eventKey="Zerg" style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
              {/* Display the Zerg Units */}
              <ZergUnits />
            </Tab.Pane>

            <Tab.Pane eventKey="Terran" style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
              {/* First 3 Terran units */}
              <TerranUnits />
            </Tab.Pane>
          </Tab.Content>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </Tab.Container>
```

Another issue I'm having is the 404 error on page refresh. I read that the Hashbrowser is a quick work around but the react router doc says its not recommended. What are some other potential solutions?

Code for routing:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter basename="starcraft2-unit-counter">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/UnitsList" element={<UnitsList />} />
            <Route path="/UnitCountersPage" element={<UnitCountersPage />} />
            <Route path="/ArmyCounterPage" element={<ArmyCounterPage />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Tried looking online for similar problems but couldn't find one..

Comment: The images not loading seems to be due to a capitalization typo. This image works if I edit the HTML in the browser on the site you linked: 
`<img src="/starcraft2-unit-counter/assets/Zerg Units/Drone.gif" alt="Drone gif" style="border-radius: 20%; height: 20vh;">`

Comment: I've used HashRouter for the GitHub Pages React Router problem, and it works fine, though it does add hashes to the URL. Here is the CRA documentation on how to handle the client-side routing issue on GitHub pages, including a trick on how to teach GitHub Pages about handling 404s: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#notes-on-client-side-routing

Comment: @esinator Oh my gosh I can't believe I didn't catch that.. Thank you for spending the time to look into it for me! Also thanks for the hashrouter info. I will spend some time reading that document